# Website's Input text field won't focus on Android Mobile

Tags: php, android, jquery, html, magento

I have a magento website in development, which has an input text field for newsletter subscription. On all devices (except Android) I am able to click on the field and it focuses and I can enter in text.

However, on Android devices, whenever I click on the field the keyboard appears and then closes itself automatically. I'm unable to focus on the field and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'newsletter/subscriber/new'; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="footer-input" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO" class="footer-submit"/>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you ever get this sorted out? i ran into this on a WordPress project

Comment: @JGallardo issue came from the viewport meta tag, it wasn't entered in correctly